# Grounding a European plug

Tags: grounding, outlet

I have a guitar amplifier which has a ground wire on its plug:

[image]

Like picture above.

On my electric outlet there is no ground wire.

If I plug it into a power strip which has a ground wire and then plug this extension cord into my outlet, is it grounded and safe?

Power strip:

[image]

**EDIT:
Thanks to everybody for your answers**

Comment: The power strip in the photo has ground / earth contacts clearly visible in the sockets but not on the plug. Add a photo of **your** power strip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if the mains outlet is not grounded, everything you connect to it will also not be grounded. And in case it is unclear, a device with grounded plug needs ground and must never ever be connected to ungrounded outlet.

Comment: Especially an instrument amplifier.  There is a long history of electric shock from guitar amps.

Answer (score 2):

No. If there is no ground on the outlet, then your amp will not be grounded, because the ground on the plug of the extension will not be connected to an outlet ground.

And, in general, you *do* want proper grounding for guitar amplifiers.